# Red-black tree for editing text

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, text-editor, red-black-tree

I was reading [this great article](http://e98cuenc.free.fr/wordprocessor/piecetable.html) by Joaquin Cuenca Abela. He talks about using a red-black tree to implement a piece table, rather than a doubly linked list.

I'm having some trouble understanding how this might relate to a buffer undergoing changes. For example, take these two buffers (original, append):

```
Hello!\0    Original
y           Append
```

And let's say the piece table looks like this:

```
buffer    start    length
original  0        2
original  5        2
append    0        1
```

We should end up with:

```
Hey!\0
```

Using a doubly linked list, this could be implemented kind of like this:

```
------------------   -------------------   ----------------
Buffer = ORIGINAL|   |Buffer = ORIGINAL|   |Buffer = APPEND
Start  = 0       |<--|Start  = 5       |<--|Start  = 0
Length = 2       |   |Length = 2       |   |Length = 1
Next   = 0x01    |-->|Next   = 0x02    |-->|Next   = NULL
Previous = NULL  |   |Previous = 0x01  |   |Previous = 0x01
------------------   -------------------   ----------------
```

If the file is originally loaded as a char array, or something, this seems really trivial and fast to run through after an edit. On the other hand, as far as I understand it, the red-black tree would look like this:

```
                       ------------------
                       size       = 2
                       size_left  = 1
                       size_right = 2
                       colour     = black
                       ------------------
                        /              \
                       /                \
                      /                  \
             ----------------      ---------------- 
             size       = 1        size       = 2
             size_left  = 0        size_left  = 0
             size_right = 0        size_right = 0
             colour     = red      colour     = red
             ----------------      ----------------
             /          \              /           \
            /            \            /             \
         NULL            NULL       NULL           NULL
```

I don't see a clear way to repaint the rest of the document after an edit. Sure, insert/delete/lookup would be faster for adding pieces to the tree. But I'm missing how one would construct the edited buffer for viewing.

What am I missing? If I had an editor, and I deleted/inserted a chunk of text, how would I traverse the tree to repaint the buffer and correctly reflect this edit? And, how would this be faster than the O(n) time complexity offered by the linked list?

Comment: @rici I think I mostly understand how the tree works, I just don't understand how, in this particular context (repainting the buffer to reflect changes) it has an advantage. Wikipedia does have a great explanation, but it doesn't cover this topic. I couldn't find any other resources that answered my question, so I asked it here

Comment: I understand that aspect; what I don't understand is how the changes made can be reflected by traversing the tree. Using the doubly linked list, it is very clear; each node points to a spot in the original and append buffer, and by keeping a running sum of the lengths of each entry, any changes made to a node can be reflected by traversing the list: ie, by choosing to print pieces of text of a certain position and length either from the original buffer or the append buffer. With the tree, how this is accomplished is not clear to me. However, I do understand rotation/having to "fix" the tree.

Comment: I think my biggest issue is struggling to fully think through an example. It would help a lot to see how I might construct a new buffer, given the information stored in the tree (in the above example, or some other example). Conceptually, it seems to me that using the linked list to construct a buffer would take O(N). But wouldn't the equivalent operation take O(NlogN) for the tree? Since, for N pieces, it takes O(logN) to retrieve its information?

Comment: On the basis of that exchange of comments, I tried to write an answer which addresses your question. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really understand the diagram you provide of the tree, because (unlike the linked list diagram) they seem to have no relation to the actual stored data. In practice, they will have essentially the same data fields (Buffer, Start and Length) plus one more, Size, which is the total size of the pieces in the subtree headed by the node. Instead of Previous and Next pointers, they will have Left and Right (child) pointers.

And, of course, they will have some extra data needed in order to maintain the tree balanced (a red/black bit in the case of red/black trees, but I don't think the mechanism for maintaining balance is important here; you could use AVL trees instead of red/black trees, for example. So I'm going to ignore that part of the node here.

The Size field is necessary in order to find the data at a given offset (and consequently, could be left out if there was never any need to do such a lookup.) I think the linked article measures Size in pieces, while I tend to measure Size in characters (or even bytes), which is what I will illustrate here. As the linked article notes, the Size field can easily be maintained in logarithmic time precisely because it refers to the Size of the subtree, rather than its location in the data stream.

You use the Size field to lookup a node by buffer offset. If the offset is less than the Size of the left child, you recurse into the left child; if it is at least the current length plus the Size of the left child, you subtract that sum from the offset and recurse into the right child. Otherwise, the current node contains the desired offset. This cannot take longer than the maximum tree depth, which is O(log N) if the tree is reasonably balanced.

I was also a bit confused by your linked list diagram, which seems to me to be representing the buffer `He|!\0|y`, while I would expect it to be `He|y|!\0`:

```
------------------   -------------------   -------------------
Buffer = ORIGINAL|   |Buffer = APPEND  |   |Buffer = ORIGINAL|
Start  = 0       |<--|Start  = 0       |<--|Start  = 5       |
Length = 2       |   |Length = 1       |   |Length = 2       |
Next   = 0x01    |-->|Next   = 0x02    |-->|Next   = NULL    |
Previous = NULL  |   |Previous = 0x01  |   |Previous = 0x01  |
------------------   -------------------   -------------------
```

The equivalent balanced tree is:

```
                       -------------------
                       | Size   = 5      |
                       | Buffer = APPEND |
                       | Start  = 0      |
                       | Length = 1      |
                       -------------------
                        /              \
                       /                \
                      /                  \
             -------------------   ------------------- 
             |Size   = 2       |   |Size   = 2       |
             |Buffer = ORIGINAL|   |Buffer = ORIGINAL|
             |Start  = 0       |   |Start  = 5       |
             |Length = 2       |   |Length = 2       |
             -------------------   -------------------
               /          \            /           \
              /            \          /             \
            NULL            NULL    NULL           NULL
```

The algorithm for finding the next node in order from a given node is as follows:

1. While the right child pointer is NULL, return to the parent. Continue to move to the parent until a node is found whose right child pointer is neither NULL nor the child being returned from.
2. Move to the right child.
3. While the left child pointer is not NULL, move to the left child

A given application of this algorithm could obviously take O(log N) iterations of steps 1 and/or 3. However, repeated applications (as in the case when you are traversing the buffer in order through a number of nodes) will be linear *in total* because any given link (parent ⇆ child) will be traversed exactly twice, once in each direction. So the total number of links traversed if walking the entire tree is twice the number of links in the tree. (And the tree has one fewer link than nodes, since it is a tree.)

---

If you measure size in characters, then you can avoid the need for the "Length" field, because the length of the data directly referred to by a Node is simply the difference between the node's subtree size and the sum of its children subtree sizes. That can (almost) reduce the size of a node to the size of the linked-list node, assuming you can find some way to encode the red/black bit (or other balancing information) in what would otherwise be padding bits.

On the other hand, it is somewhat common to see binary tree implementations with parent pointers, as well as two child pointers. (It's clear how this can help by looking at the traverse algorithm above.) However, it is not necessary to store parent pointers because they can, for example, be maintained during any given traverse of a tree in an array of parent pointers indexed by depth in the tree. This array is obviously no larger than the maximum tree depth, so a small (~50) fixed-length array could be used.

These optimisations are also well beyond this answer.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. I definitely messed up the order of the linked list. The size attribute is what I was failing to understand fully, I think. Now this seems a lot more clear. Lastly, if it takes linear time to traverse the whole tree, then is the tree faster than the linked list in most situations (lookup/insertion/deletion) EXCEPT when constructing a buffer based on a piece table? In which case they both take linear time?

Comment: The big advantage is lookup, I think. AIUI, you would normally construct the buffer initially from a few large pieces; there is a linear algo for constructing a RB tree from a presorted sequence, but I don't see that as important. Once you've found the endpoints, insert and delete will have pretty similar times. So lookup is critical.

Answer (score 0):

> If I had an editor, and I deleted/inserted a chunk of text, how would I traverse the tree to repaint the buffer and correctly reflect this edit? And, how would this be faster than the O(n) time complexity offered by the linked list?

Assume the piece table is large and that repainting the portion of the buffer visible on the screen typically requires visiting only a few consecutive nodes. 
 Suppose the nodes you need to visit after a particular edit are in the middle or near the end of the document.

With a doubly-linked list, you may need to walk through many nodes from the beginning table to get to the beginning of the edit.  That's O(n).  From there, you walk through the next few nodes to do the painting.

With a balanced tree, you can find that first node in O(log_2 n).  From there, you do an in-order traversal to visit the next few nodes that are needed for painting.

Updating the positions in the tree after adding, removing, or modifying a piece is a simply matter of adding/subtracting a value from the positions of the ancestors starting with the parent of the new/modified node.  That, too, is O(log_2 n).